# JQuery scroll action repeated the result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to load more products with an ajax call when the page reaches the end.

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(document).height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
        var _token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
        var theurl = 'homePaginate';
        console.log(skip_arr);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: theurl,
            data:{_token:_token,page:page,avoid:skip_arr},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                page+=1;
                printProducts(data,false,true,true)

            }
        });
    }
});
```

I use a function to loop over my product to print it, in ajax call I send the `page` number and some times i need to avoid some products to show

```
function printProducts(data,is_ad,get_void,is_animate) {
    console.log(page);
    for (i=0;i< data.length;i++){
        var id = '#col'+columnIndex;

        columnIndex++;
        if (columnIndex == 6){
            columnIndex = 1;
        }
        var stars = '';

        for(star = 0 ;star < Math.floor(data[i]['rate']);star++){
            stars += '<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
        }
        var fraction = data[i]['rate']%1;
        if (fraction > 0 ){
            stars += '<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>';
            for(star = 0 ;star < 4-data[i]['rate'];star++){
                stars += '<i class="far fa-star"></i>';
            }

        }else{
            for(star = 0 ;star < 5-data[i]['rate'];star++){
                stars += '<i class="far fa-star"></i>';
            }
        }
        var discount ='';
        if (data[i]['runningDiscount']){
            discount = '<span class="discount-tag">'+data[i]['discount']['valuePercentage']+'% Off</span>';
        }
        if(get_void){
            skip_arr.push(data[i]['id']);
        }

        var isFavorite = data[i]['isFavourite']?'fas':'far';

        var image = '{{ url('') }}'+'/'+data[i]["image"];

        var url = '{{ url('product') }}'+'/'+data[i]["id"];

        var quick_cart = '';
        if (data[i]["quickCart"] === true){
            quick_cart = 'class="quick-add" data-item-id="'+data[i]['item']["id"]+'"';
        }else{
            quick_cart = 'href="'+url+'"';
        }

        var ad = '';
        if (is_ad) ad = ' <span class="ad">Ad</span>';

        var animate = '';
        if(is_animate){
            animate = ' animated  fadeInDown ';
        }
        var product = '<div class="col-xs-12 product'+animate+'" data-id="'+id+'">\n' +
            '                                <div class="row product-body">\n' +ad+ // print ad tag
            '                                    <span class="actions">\n' +
            '                                        <a '+quick_cart+'>\n' +
            '                                            <img src="{{ asset("site_assets/img/cart.png") }}" class="product-cart">\n' +
            '                                        </a>\n' +
            '                                        <a>\n' +
            '                                            <i class="'+isFavorite+' fa-heart shoptizer-color" data-id="'+data[i]["id"]+'"></i>\n' +
            '                                        </a>\n' +
            '                                    </span>\n' +
            '                                    <span class="view-icon" data-id='+ data[i]["id"]+'>\n' +
            '                                            <img src="{{ asset("site_assets/img/eye.png") }}">\n' +
            '                                    </span>\n' +discount+
            '                                <img class="img-fluid" src="'+image+'">\n' +
            '                                <a href='+url+' class="product-link"></a>'+
            '                            </div>\n' +
            '                            <div class="col-sm-12">\n' +
            '                                <span>'+data[i]['name']+' </span>\n' +
            '                                <h6 class="shoptizer-color price">'+data[i]['price']+' EGP</h6>\n' +
            '                            </div>\n' +
            '                            <div class="col-xs-12 p-rate">\n' +stars+'</div>\n' +
            '                        </div>';
        $(id).append(product);
    }
}
```

So when I reach the end it works fine but while testing the client scrolled up and down, so I got a repeated product in two rows. Why is that and how can I prevent it?

I think the problem in `$(window).scroll()`!!

Comment: can you show your `printProducts()` method and what is the purpose of `page:page,avoid:skip_arr`

Comment: of course I will update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem was in my ajax call I update the page on the success function so if the user reached the bottom twice before the request respond it duplicate the printed data because it send the same page so same response.

so the solution for me was to update the page

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
        var _token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
        var theurl = 'homePaginate';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: theurl,

            data:{_token:_token,page:page,avoid:skip_arr},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {         
                printProducts(data,false,true,true)
            }
        });
      page+=1;
    }
});
```

Comment: that `page+=1;` seems misplaced there.  IF this is a self answer and works, you should accept it.

Comment: I faced that issue and I can't accept it until tomorrow